# Does background services count in Firebase's currently active users?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an application using background services (foreground in API 26+), and I'm implementing firebase analytics. Does firing the service count as a user activity in firebase? and does it differ between foreground services and background services in pre-oreo OS version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, usage is determined based on activities, not services.